# function error: missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed cpos() (cwhmisc)

Tags: r, text-mining, na

This is my first post, I am quite new to R (one month) so I might have some really stupid mistake here.

I am trying to write a function to:

1. input the starting pattern and ending pattern
2. extract sub-string (in between the starting and ending pattern)
3. store the returned string value to a data frame

My sample string looks like this:

> tweedehands?merkIds=9fdc7e2d-b40c-4ee6-896d-9f0453cb39c6&modelIds.9fdc7e2d-b40c-4ee6-896d-9f0453cb39c6=d56286d3-cecc-4183-9b6d-9c7e241de6c1&minimumprijs=5000&maximumprijs=6000&minimumbouwjaar=&maximumbouwjaar=&minimumkilometerstand=&maximumkilometerstand=&postcode=&afstand=

For example, I want to extract the value after `minimumprijs=` and before `&`, the function should return `5000`

```
install.packages("cwhmisc")
library("cwhmisc")
getFilter <- function(x, STAchar = NA, ENDchar = "&"){
  x<- as.character(x)
  # pre-allocate a vector to store the extracted strings
  snippet = rep(0, length(x))
  for (i in 1:length(x))
   {#extract the initial position
      staPostion = (cpos(x[i], STAchar, 1) + nchar(STAchar))

    # extract the final position
      endPostion = (cpos(x[i], ENDchar, staPostion) - length(ENDchar))

    # extract the substring between the initial and final positions, inclusively
    snippet[i] = substr(x[i], staPostion, endPostion)
   }
  return(snippet)
}
```

However, this function is not working for me and I don't really understand what is the problem.

The error it returns is as follow:

> Error in if (start + lsub1 > lstr) return(NA) else { : 
>         missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>       Called from: cpos(x[i], ENDchar, staPostion)
>       Browse[1]>

Now I can only think about to add some Error Handling, NA Handling lines inside of the function. But maybe it is something else.

Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: Regex would make this much easier: `getFilter <- function(start, stop, string){pat <- paste0(if(!is.na(start)){paste0('.*', start)}, '(.+?)', if(!is.na(stop)){paste0(stop, '.*')}); sub(pat, '\\1', string)}`

Comment: Are you using additional packages that are not listed in your post? If so, please add them in your code or mention them in your text. For example `cpos`, the cause of your error message, is not a function in base R.

Comment: I used cpos {cwhmisc} only, sorry forgot to mention it in the post

Comment: hi @alistaire, I am not really familiar with regular expression, so if I want to extract all the texts between  "minimumprijs=" and the next "&", how should I write the function?

Comment: Using the above function, `getFilter("minimumprijs=", "&", s)` where `s` is the whole string. Just using `sub` directly, `sub(".*minimumprijs=(.*?)&.*", '\\1', s)`. [Here's an explanation of how it matches the pattern,](https://regex101.com/r/bC9gP9/1), and it replaces the whole match with the first captured group `\\1`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all your help, but I just found out there is a more efficient way to achieve the same function by using str_locate and substr